# How to use custom icon by importing a font in CSS

Tags: css

I would like to use an icon in CSS using @import from https://www.dafont.com/arrow-7.font. For some reason the icon doesn't load. Any idea what am I doing wrong here ?
Thank you!

```
<div class="icon">

</div>



@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url("myserverDirectory/arrow_7.tff");
}

.icon {
height:40px;
width:40px;
font-family:myFirstFont;
content:'/0112';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content` is a valid property for pseudo elements only, e.g.:

```
.icon::before{
  content: '/0112';
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'myFirstFont';
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
```

The font does load otherwise.